# Text file parsing by Python

Tags: python

I am new to Python. Please help me in parsing these files..

> > port=4050 SOH= hostname=BlueVectorEMA uptime=N/A SHTSOT=N/A
> >     iCenter=N/A start=51808152 stop=518083AA cycles=0.0 tagCnt=23
> >     C1Gen1=0.0.0.0 C1Gen2=0.0.0.0 STX= 00045512=119,59,55,60,50,C,00,N/A
> >     00052450=120,60,44,60,43,C,00,N/A 00042260=113,54,51,59,43,C,00,N/A
> >     00046999=114,56,46,58,42,C,00,N/A 00043166=117,58,46,59,42,C,00,N/A
> >     00052651=113,55,48,58,42,C,00,N/A 00050594=118,59,43,59,43,C,00,N/A
> >     00051774=120,60,44,60,42,C,00,N/A 00056767=119,59,43,60,42,C,00,N/A
> >     00043181=109,51,56,58,45,C,00,N/A 00033333=115,56,55,59,43,C,00,N/A
> >     00031475=115,57,43,58,45,C,00,N/A 00042817=118,59,48,59,50,C,00,N/A
> >     00054245=118,58,45,60,41,C,00,N/A 00043589=118,58,46,60,43,C,00,N/A
> >     00053037=116,57,54,59,48,C,00,N/A 00053636=114,55,45,59,42,C,00,N/A
> >     00045642=116,57,49,59,42,C,00,N/A 00045591=118,59,46,59,45,C,00,N/A
> >     00033114=116,58,46,58,44,C,00,N/A 00042075=114,56,54,58,48,C,00,N/A
> >     00044491=113,55,42,58,43,C,00,N/A
> >     00000587=18,0,999,18,46,T,403/002,0030H/3.0 ETX= EOT=
> >     timestamp=5180a211
> >
> > > logdir=2013-05
> > >
> > > Wed May  1 00:03:13 2013
> > >       -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- port=4050 SOH= hostname=BlueVectorEMA uptime=N/A SHTSOT=N/A
> > >       iCenter=N/A start=518083AA stop=51808602 cycles=0.0 tagCnt=23
> > >       C1Gen1=0.0.0.0 C1Gen2=0.0.0.0 STX= 00053636=119,59,44,60,41,C,00,N/A
> > >       00043181=107,48,56,59,45,C,00,N/A 00046999=116,57,46,59,42,C,00,N/A
> > >       00031475=117,58,43,59,45,C,00,N/A 00053037=115,55,54,60,48,C,00,N/A
> > >       00052651=117,58,47,59,42,C,00,N/A 00042075=117,57,54,60,48,C,00,N/A
> > >       00050594=118,59,43,59,43,C,00,N/A 00045512=115,55,55,60,50,C,00,N/A
> > >       00044491=113,55,42,58,43,C,00,N/A 00033114=115,57,46,58,44,C,00,N/A
> > >       00045591=117,58,46,59,46,C,00,N/A 00052450=117,58,44,59,43,C,00,N/A
> > >       00042260=114,56,51,58,42,C,00,N/A 00043166=116,58,47,58,42,C,00,N/A
> > >       00042817=117,59,48,58,50,C,00,N/A 00056767=119,59,43,60,42,C,00,N/A
> > >       00054245=119,59,45,60,41,C,00,N/A 00043589=117,57,46,60,43,C,00,N/A
> > >       00051774=118,59,44,59,42,C,00,N/A 00045642=113,55,50,58,42,C,00,N/A
> > >       00033333=111,53,55,58,44,C,00,N/A
> > >       00000587=7,0,999,7,47,T,402/202,0028H/2.5 ETX= EOT= timestamp=5180a469
> > >       logdir=2013-05
>
> ### Wed May  1 00:13:13 2013

Description:

- Left side of equals (=) is my table filed name
- Right side of equals (=) is my table field value
- STX has multiple values varies by file.
- time stamp = unix time stamp and would like to convert to Windows CST
- Record seperator for each record is --> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------  (each log file has several thousand records seperated by string)

My basics of Python programming are not helping me converting these file to meaningful structured mode. Appreciate for your guidance in this.

Comment: Show us what code you have already tried, and where it doesn't work.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you load the file and read one line at a time? Where is your code?

Comment: what have you so far?

Comment: I was able to read the file but I was not able to bring all STH records to one place. My desired out is... STH record|Port|timestamp "00045642=113,55,50,58,42,C,00,N/A 00033333=111,53,55,58,44,C,00,N/A|port|timestamp"

Comment: please, post your code. edit your question, don't post strings/code here in comment-section

Answer (score 0):

Read the file record by record (usually a for loop).
Parse each record.
Store them.

You need to read up on how to:

Open a file in read mode and read it.

String manipulation. It's just another API; a powerful easy one at that, for this job. Read the docs. splitlines, find, startswith, split, slicing, etc

Open a file in write mode and save stuff to it. This generally includes navigating the filesystem using the os.path module

Comment: How I handle my "STX= " string? STH is dynamic in each record. Or can I read all STH records and add time stamps for each record? In this file main fields are STH, Time stamp, port (3 main fields).